# Netbeans Platform Project using Mediator Pattern - Is it possible?

Tags: java, design-patterns, netbeans, netbeans-platform, mediator

I want to use the mediator design pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) in my netbeans platform modular app. However, I am not sure how to do this on startup, since there does not seem to be a good way to create my mediator and then inject it into each module.

Does anyone know a good way to do this? Do I have to resort to using the Lookup API or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to the NetBeans platform and inter-modular communications most answers boil down to the lookup :)

Using the sample code that you gave I'd do the following

```
@ServiceProvider(service = Mediator.class)
class Mediator{..}
```

The [ServiceProvider](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util-lookup/org/openide/util/lookup/ServiceProvider.html) annotation is a NetBeans extension to the [ServiceLoader mechanism](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/08/12/simple-dependency-injection-serviceloader-jdk-6) that automates the work of having to put values in the META-INF/services folder.

The ButtonView class would be modified as follows

```
class BtnView extends JButton implements Command {

    Mediator med = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(Mediator.class);

    BtnView(ActionListener al, Mediator m) {
        super("View");
        addActionListener(al);
        med = m;
        med.registerView(this);
    }

    public void execute() {
        med.view();
    }

}
```

I'm not really familiar with the Mediator pattern, so I hope my understanding passes muster in as much as that you can understand the example.

For more examples see these sites

- [NetBeans Platform QuickStart](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-quick-start.html)
- [NetBeans Platform – how to register a class as a provider of multiple services](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/netbeans-platform-how-to-register-a-class-as-a-provider-of-multiple-services/)
- [NetBeans Lookups explained](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/netbeans-lookups-explained)
- [NetBeans Developer FAQ - Lookup](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Lookup)

Comment: I was not sure why the @ServiceProvider annotation was recommended, but when I read your second link down at the bottom, it said it is just a way to add a class by default to the global lookup. I will try this out and update my question later with some info on how well this worked.

Comment: One question I have about this approach is whether or not the Mediator's data be changed dynamically when another module changes it. Will the Lookup.getDefault return the same reference to all modules that call it and not a clone to each module?

Comment: @Makoto Each module will get the same instance, so changes made in the one module will be visible in another module.